# Why Magento Go link is still coming in admin header?

Tags: admin, ce-1.9.1.0, header, magento-go

There is a link in Magento 1.9+ admin still coming in header. Something like

```
Try Magento Go for Free
```

But Magento Go was closed. Is it a bug, or something missed? Or Why is it there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was removed in v1.9.1.0. Compare the two files:

- [app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv @ v1.9.0.0](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.9.0.0/app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv)
- [app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv @ v1.9.1.0](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.9.1.0/app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv)

You can see "Magento Go" referenced in the first, but not the second.